# I can't upload images using multer and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, multer

I want to upload image using a jade form then i want to show it in a posts page the problem is the images are uploaded as files with no extension and then i get Cannot read property 'mainimage' of undefined

**My app.js code is below**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './public/images/uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
    }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('mainimage');
```

**Then my posts.js**

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res, nect){
    // Get The Form Values
    var title       = req.body.title;
    var category    = req.body.category;
    var body        = req.body.body;
    var author      = req.body.author;
    var date        = new Date();

    if(req.file.mainimage){
        var mainImageOriginalName   = req.file.mainimage.originalname;
        var mainImageName           = req.file.mainimage.name;
        var mainImageMime           = req.file.mainimage.mimetype;
        var mainImagePath           = req.file.mainimage.path;
        var mainImageExt            = req.file.mainimage.extension;
        var mainImageSize           = req.file.mainimage.size;
    } else{
        var mainImageName = 'noimage.png';
    }

    //Form Validation
    req.checkBody('title', 'Title field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('body', 'Body field is required');

    //Check errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
     res.render('addpost',{
         "errors": errors,
         "title": title,
         "body": body
     });   
    } else{
        var posts = db.get('posts');

        //submit to db
        posts.insert({
            "title": title,
            "body": body,
            "category": category,
            "date": date,
            "author": author,
            "mainimage": mainImageName
        }, function(err, post){
            if(err){
                res.send('There was an issue submitting the post');
            } else{
                req.flash('success', 'Post Submitted');
                res.location('/');
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    }

});
```

**And this my posts.jade Form**

```
form(method='post', action='/posts/add', enctype='multipart/form-data')
        .form-group
            label Title:
            input.form-control(name='title', type='text')
        .form-group
            label Category
            select.form-control(name='category')
                each category, i in categories
                    option(value='#{category.title}') #{category.title}
        .form-group
            label Body
            textarea.form-control(name='body', id='body')
        .form-group
            label Main Image:
            input.form-control(name='mainimage', type='file', id='mainimage')
```

**And here is where i want to display it**

```
each post, i in posts
            .posts
                h1
                    a(href='/posts/show/#{post._id}')
                        =post.title
                p.meta Posted in #{post.category} by #{post.author} on #{moment(post.date).format('MM-DD-YYYY')}
                img(src='/images/uploads/#{post.mainimage}')
                !=post.body
                a.more(href='/posts/show/#{post._id}') Read More
```

Answer (score 0):

The extension problem is probably because in your `storage` you name your file without the extension.

To add it, you can insert this code in your `storage` method.

```
filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    var extension = file.mimetype;
    extension = extension.substring(extension.indexOf("/")+1, extension.length);
    var filename = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + "." + extension;
    callback(null, filename);
}
```

Also, if you don't have your directory mapped, you can insert in you `app.js` a static mapping to the folder where you saved the file, like this:

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
```

Then, in your `post` page you can access the downloaded file directly via its URL, using `http://yourdomain:port/images/<filename.extension>`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried what you told me but still gives me 
**Cannot read property 'mainimage' of undefined**

Comment: Tells me the error at posts.js line 27 

`if(req.file.mainimage){
        var mainImageOriginalName   = req.file.mainimage.originalname;
        var mainImageName           = req.file.mainimage.name;
        var mainImageMime           = req.file.mainimage.mimetype;
        var mainImagePath           = req.file.mainimage.path;
        var mainImageExt            = req.file.mainimage.extension;
        var mainImageSize           = req.file.mainimage.size;
    } else{
        var mainImageName = 'noimage.png';
    }`

Comment: I don't have your line numbers, but after the `storage` method, in your `post` method, you can get the name getting this from `req.body.mainImage`.

Comment: I tried using `req.body.mainimage` instead and it worked but it tells me now that **Cannot read property 'length' of undefined** 
of this line 
`each category, i in categories`
   `option(value='#{category.title}') #{category.title}`
which was working before i try the `req.body.mainimage`

Comment: I don't know how JADE handles that loop, but you will have to debug it to check exactly what's in your `post` object to see which property you're accessing that is `undefilned`.